# effects of initializing git repository on linux root directory 3:)

Tags: backup, restore, git

I am running beaglebone black on ubuntu installed on sd card. i am learning to program the device in trial and error method by installing various packages (just like CERN guys study sub atomic particles by hitting them together in various angles and studying their trajectories). So can i initialize a git repository at root directory and ignore volatile directories like /sys and /proc? Or watching what system directories is sufficient to successfully time track entire OS? Are there any similar snapshoting tools? Other than git, what repository system is best to time track binary files?

How to change filesystem to [ZFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zfs)? During ubuntu installation am i provided with ZFS filesytem option in addition to extX, FAT, NTFS etc. filesystems, I never noticed?

--EDIT--

What is list of non-volatile and important(unlike `/tmp`) directories in `/`?

Comment: "During ubuntu installation am i provided with ZFS filesytem option" I highly doubt that - there's only an unofficial ZFS on Linux port. It cannot be included because of the licence incompatibility with the GPL kernel.

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to accomplish? Do you need to **audit** systems (security)? Do you need to *snapshot* for quick **recovery** procedures? Because I don't quite understand "time track" here - it's not too specific. I can provide an answer for Git, but I really think you don't want to use Git for this.

Comment: @gertvdijk In OSX or Solaris they used the name Time Machine for the application that restores operating system to earlier date. Yes i need snapshot for quick recover procedures.

Comment: Ah, that clarifies a bit! Please **edit** your question to reflect that! Several options to go from here: Btrfs with subvolumes, LVM snapshots and ZFS on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

first, I don't think that git is a good solution for binary files.

maybe is better to use virtual machine in virtualbox where you can create snapshots (as many as you need) of entire system

to change filesystem (how I know) you need to format the partition
(don't know about zfs, but you can use Gparted, maybe he can, gparted is an advanced partition manager, user friendly)